# CSS3 multi background position left & right on iOS

Tags: ios, html, css

How to make the position of the background on the left and right side?

The desired result:

[image: The desired result]

The current result iOS:

[[image]]

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./index_files/styles.css">
<script src="./index_files/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
@-webkit-keyframes adv{
    0%,20%,100% {
        background:url(../index_files/costa-bg2.png) top left no-repeat,url(../index_files/costa-bg3.png) top right no-repeat;
    }
}

html,body {
    width:100%;height:100%;
}

body{
    -webkit-animation:adv 35s linear 0s infinite;animation:adv 35s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example (snippet, jsfiddle, or similar) reproducing your problem ?

Comment: Example https://jsfiddle.net/phs7ff9h/